# jquery form validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

i got my jquery form validation plugin from [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) but i cannot seem to make the validation work for me. Here is my [codes](http://jsfiddle.net/hyH4t/1/) but it doesnt work because i didnt upload the plugin as part of this example. Sorry about that but can someone view through my Jquery scripts and provide some advice? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why isnt the js files of jquery and the validation form on the header?

Comment: what do u mean? fiddle will auto import jquery and this is the example i referred to: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/